# My simple javascript slideshow isn't working when added to Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have this very simple slideshow that I want to use on my Shopify store, nevertheless, it doesn't work when added to Shopify. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

In codepen or jsfiddle the code seems to be working fine, but when I add it in there just by loading the js in a  tag, it suddenly doesn't work anymore.

Thanks a lot for helping me out, I'm sure it's just some simple mistake from my end.

https://jsfiddle.net/Elias__Nielsen/m63quydn/2/

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')
let current = 1

const nextSlide = () => {
  current = current === slides.length ? 1 : current + 1
}
const prevSlide = () => {
  current = current === 1 ? slides.length : current - 1
}

const slideTo = (direction) => {
  document.querySelector(`.slide${current}`).classList.remove('active')
  direction === 'prev' ? prevSlide() : nextSlide()
  document.querySelector(`.slide${current}`).classList.add('active')
}

document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item')
  .forEach(navItem => navItem.addEventListener('click', () => slideTo(navItem.dataset.slide)))
```

```css
  .wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.0s;
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  aspect-ratio: 5 / 3;
}

.slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.slide.active {
  flex-grow: 10;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em 1em 0;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: -33%;
}

.slider-controls span {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-item {
  z-index: 4;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Old versions of Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Fire
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1 active">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0586/1756/1294/files/Double_OX_Horn_Compressed.webp?v=1663333602">
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0586/1756/1294/files/Solo_OX_Horn_ooo.webp?v=1663333602">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-controls navigation">
    <span class="nav-item" data-slide="prev">
     <
    </span>
    <span class="nav-item" data-slide="next">
     >
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there errors in your console? That would be the first thing to check.

Comment: How and where are you adding the code to shopify?